# Unit Testing Java code in Android app generated using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, ibm-mobilefirst

I've been trying to execute a unit testing an Android Class using Junit but I've noticed that all of the tutorials I've encountered are saying to edit `build.gradle` to specify the test. My Android Application is a Hybrid Application and it is generated using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation. According to their website, [link here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-up-the-android-development-environment/?replytocom=3648#comment-3652), that Gradle is not supported.

Are there other ways to execute Unit Testing of the Android Code even if Gradle is not supported?

Comment: Gradle is just a means to add the required framework (JUnit) to your application. So, if Gradle is not supported why not just add it the old fashioned way to your Android application? Also, other than reading about, have you actually tried to follow any specific guide?

Comment: But it's not _supported_ by MobileFirst right? Won't there be any issues that could occur if I find ways to add Gradle to my project? Also, I've tried adding the Gradle Plugin, apparently an error saying, "Fail to load plugin descriptor from file android-gradle-plugin-dsl.zip"occured.

Comment: I wrote, use it *without* Gradle. Try *without* Gradle. JUnit worked with Android and Java before Gradle existed.

Comment: I've been searching in Google for a few days already and all the sites I could remember that I checked and tried following are as follows: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html, http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support, https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/. I've also added the Junit library but I kept on having the same errors same to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591504/android-studio-import-existing-unit-tests-unable-to-find-instrumentation-info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to unit test your java code that *includes any Android classes in the call stack of the code under test*, you must do one of the following:

- build instrumented unit tests (meaning, use an [instrumentation runner](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html))
- use a mock framework such as [mockito](http://mockito.org/) or [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)

If you are unit testing your java code that does *not* include any Android classes in the call stack of the code under test, you simply put junit in your classpath, and execute the test.

None of these instructions are due to limitations, or "lack of support", from MobileFirst Platform.  The "unsupported" statement simply indicates that the choice of test technique is yours.